# creating a sql table

Tags: sql

I am trying to create my first SQL table and I am getting a syntax error and cannot figure out why. Here is my code:

```
create table ps 
(
  USER VARCHAR(20),
  PID INT(10),
  %CPU DECIMAL(4),
  %MEM DECIMAL(4),
  VSZ INT(10),
  RSS INT(10),
  TTY VARCHAR(10),
  STAT VARCHAR(5),
  START VARCHAR(20),
  TIME VARCHAR(20),
  COMMAND VARCHAR(20)
);
```

Comment: The % in %CPU and %MEM looks suspicious. Did you try without the % yet? You can always delete the table and try again.

Comment: When asking about a specific error, you must *always* include the actual error you're talking about.

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using, and what error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

As Sarah suggested, you are setting strange names to your columns, remove `%`

```
create table ps 
(
  USER VARCHAR(20),
  PID INT(10),
  PERC_CPU DECIMAL(4),
  PERC_MEM DECIMAL(4),
  VSZ INT(10),
  RSS INT(10),
  TTY VARCHAR(10),
  STAT VARCHAR(5),
  START VARCHAR(20),
  TIME VARCHAR(20),
  COMMAND VARCHAR(20)
);
```